# render html from Google apps script html template

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, gmail

I'm working on standalone web app using Google apps script based on html template. The purpose of the app is kind of a simple gmail but with custom filter.  I'v already done that filter and show the list of emails but got stuck on the problem with rendering html body of a message.

Here's the part of code:

Html template:

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>
<script>
...
             for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
             {
             var row = table.insertRow(0);
             row.setAttribute("messageId", threads[i].id);
             row.onclick = (function() {
             google.script.run.openMessage(this.getAttribute("messageId"));
             });
             var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
             cell1.innerHTML = threads[i].subject;
             }
...
</script>
```

Google script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlServi‌​ce.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

...

function openMessage(id)
{
var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(id);
var body = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(message.getBody());
}
...
```

The question is:  What are the best way to show the message body on click? When I try to open it in new window (`window.open()...`)b it trows an error, modal window isn't working from html template as well.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question, it is - jquery dialog box.

```
<div id="dialog"></div>

function openDialog(html) {
    $("#dialog-confirm").html(html);

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        title: "Message",
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
    });
}
```